# Start CMD.exe from powershell with arguments in a script block?

Tags: powershell, cmd

Is this possible?

I've just been trying something simple:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" -verb runas -ArgumentList {echo hello1}
```

CMD starts in admin, but nothing happens after that.

The long story is, when I want to use "Remove-Item" I do not want to use the -Recurse argument because it will throw access denied errors for various reasons. The only way I know how to do it without any prompts is using rmdir inside a command prompt window.

Does anyone know a way to either suppress the prompt without -recurse or how I could start CMD and call rmdir with all its parameters?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Paul G's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52825448/45375) solves your immediate problem based on the sample command in your question and helpfully points out that **`/c` must precede any command to pass to `cmd.exe`** (or `/k`, if you want to keep the session open).

While **using a script block** with `Start-Process`'s `-ArgumentList` parameter can be convenient, you should know its **limitations**:

- The script block's *literal contents* becomes a *single string* argument that is passed to `-ArgumentList`.
- Therefore, **use of a script block prevents use of PowerShell variables and expressions** as (parts of) the arguments to pass.

Therefore, **more work is needed if you want to pass the target directory path by way of a *variable***:

```
$targetDir = 'c:\foo\bar' 
Start-Process -Wait -FilePath cmd -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList '/c', 
  'echo', 'rmdir', '/s', "`"$targetDir`""
```

<sup>Note that I've added `echo` so as to *preview* the `rmdir` command - remove it to perform actual deletion.</sup>

Note the use of *embedded* double-quoting around `$targetDir`, which, unfortunately, is necessary to pass arguments with embedded spaces properly, due to a 
a [known bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5576).

Also note the `-Wait` switch, which ensures that the command doesn't return until the elevated process has exited - though that in itself doesn't guarantee *successful* completion, which you'd have to check for afterwards.

You could add `-WindowStyle Hidden` to run the elevated console window itself invisibly, but note that the UAC dialog (to confirm elevation) will obviously still show - unless your PowerShell session already *is* elevated.

---

As for:

> When I want to use `Remove-Item` I do not want to use the `-Recurse` argument because it will throw access denied errors for various reasons.

In order to remove an entire directory with `Remove-Item` - including all its contents, including subdirectories - you *must* use `-Recurse`.

You can force *certain* deletions to occur without complaint with `-Force` (such as files marked as read-only), but deletion attempts that lack the required *permissions* will never succeed.

While you can suppress the associated *error messages* with `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`, the items in questions won't be deleted, and running the code *elevated* may again be your only choice.

Answer (score 14):

You pretty much have the whole thing.  Just add a `/c` or `/k` at the beginning of your argument list.

`/c` - close command prompt after i run my command
`/k` - keep command prompt open

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" -verb runas -ArgumentList {/c echo hello1}
```